# In PHP str_replace can be ORing or Not?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to know that if i want to replace string in PHP than can i use pipe sigh | for mainly we use for ORing condition. If yes than please tell me how ?

In preg_replace we used pipe | sigh for ORing two regex. same way here I can do for str_replace?

I have below two code i have to compress and make it smaller **without using array** It can possible If yes than please tell me How ?

```
$minit = strpos($arry[$x],"Lv.");
if($minit == true){
    $a = str_replace('Lv.','LOVE',$arry1[$x]);
    array_splice($arry1, $x, 1, $a);
}
$minit1 = strpos($arry[$x],"Lv&#x2E;");
if($minit1 == true){
    $a = str_replace('Lv&#x2E;','LOVE',$arry1[$x]);
    array_splice($arry1, $x, 1, $a);
}
```

I have to compressed it and make it smaller than it's look like. How can i do that ?

Comment: You already tagged this with `preg-replace`, so probably know that this is the better option here. What's stopping you from ditching `str_replace` then?

Comment: But i want to use str_replace here. any create it's short form is that any other way ?

Comment: Using preg_replace can i do that ? If yes than HOW ? please leave comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with `al|ter|nati|ves`.

```
$var = preg_replace("/  EXAMpl&#101;  | EX\.  /x", "REPL", $var);
```

Take note to `\` escape any meta characters (`.` or `[]` or `()` etc.), und use regex delimiters. See the manual for details or http://regexp.info/ for an introduction.